# VBA Chrome save as pdf when popup comes

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried to save the chrome popup page as PDF. Unfortunately, I am finding difficulty in saving the page as pdf with specific s.no. from cell/Range.
Need help in saving / print & save as PDF with given specific number from cell/Range.

```
.FindElementByCss("[type='search']").SendKeys Cells(i, 1)
.FindElementByXPath("//a[@onclick='ShowSolidManifest(""" & Cells(i, 1) & """);return false;']").Click
    .Window.SwitchToNextWindow
    .Window.Maximize
    .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(190,1200);")
    Cells(i, 1).Copy
    .FindElementByCss("[class='noPrint']").Click  // 1st Image[Only Print][1]
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"  //This is not working as click on print, 
                       another window[Only Print][1] pops up to save- 2nd Image
    .Window.Activate
    .Window.Close  // 2nd Image[2nd Alert window to save as PDF][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM5GG.jpg)